# Splitting and reording in an orthonormal basis

Tags: sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces

Suppose I have a Hilbert space $H$ with countable orthonormal basis $\{e_n \}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}$. Every orthonormal basis is an example of an unconditional Schauder basis, meaning if I write $x\in H$ as
$$
x=\sum_{n\geq 0} c_n e_n, \quad |c_n|<\infty
$$
then I can rearrange the terms in the sum in any way I like and the series will still converge to $x$.

Now, suppose I split the coefficients $c_n$ into finite sums of another finite set of coefficients, that is for each $n$ I write 
$$
c_n=\sum_{m=0}^{K_n}b_{nm}, \quad |b_{nm}|<\infty,\quad K_n<\infty
$$

**Question:** Can I still reorder the resulting series in any way I like? To give an example of what I mean, suppose $K_0=1$, $K_j=0$, $j>1$. So I have
$$
x=(b_{00}+b_{01})e_0 +\sum_{n\geq 1}c_1 e_1
$$
Can I then move $b_{01} e_0$ to any position I like and write 
$$
x=b_{00} e_0 +c_1 e_1 + \dots + b_{01} e_0 + \dots\quad 
$$
or is it crucial that I keep all $e_n$ together?

Comment: I expect that the answer is positive because each $K_n$ is finite, for each $n$ I can compute $\langle e_n,x\rangle$ and find the same value. We could run into trouble if $K_n$ were infinite though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any vector in $H$ is uniquely defined by the coordinate projections $\langle e_n,x\rangle$. Since each $K_n$ is finite one can reorder the basis vectors in any desired way and this will not affect the coordinate values.